# IntPtr.ToInt32() Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHR() - Querying the GAC

Tags: c#, .net, interop, gac, fusion

I've been using some code I've found on the net to query the GAC using the fusion.dll however I've recently been getting a few error reports back complaining of an OverflowException.

```
    // If assemblyName is not fully qualified, a random matching may be returned!!!!
    public static String QueryAssemblyInfo(String assemblyName)
    {
        ASSEMBLY_INFO assembyInfo = new ASSEMBLY_INFO();
        assembyInfo.cchBuf = 512;
        assembyInfo.currentAssemblyPath = new String('\0',
        assembyInfo.cchBuf);
        IAssemblyCache assemblyCache = null;
        // Get IAssemblyCache pointer
        IntPtr hr = GacApi.CreateAssemblyCache(out assemblyCache, 0);
        if (hr == IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            hr = assemblyCache.QueryAssemblyInfo(1, assemblyName, ref assembyInfo);
            if (hr != IntPtr.Zero)
                Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHR(hr.ToInt32());
        }
        else
            Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHR(hr.ToInt32());
        return assembyInfo.currentAssemblyPath;
    }
```

The offending code is when its trying to convert the IntPtr to a Int32 when its actually an Int64, but the problem is the Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHR only accepts an Int32 so I'm a bit stuck for what to do. At the moment I'm just handling the exception but I'd like to know what is the correct way of doing it?

Marlon

Comment: Your test is wrong too, an HRESULT is only an error code if the value < 0.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check the signature on your `DllImport` for `CreateAssemblyCache`.  It looks like it should be `int`, not `IntPtr`

```
[DllImport("fusion.dll")]
internal static extern int CreateAssemblyCache(
    out IAssemblyCache ppAsmCache, int reserved);
```

Comment: thanks, I've just checked the definitions of both the Create and Query methods and your correct they both return ints.

Answer (score 4):

Why are you using an `IntPtr` to hold the value of an HRESULT? The size of an HRESULT is not platform dependent, it is always 32 bits, so you should use either `int` or `uint` to hold the value. Change the code to use one of these instead, and the problem will go away.

Comment: assemblyCache.QueryAssemblyInfo() returns an IntPtr. My basic type knowledge is rusty, if I convert it to an uInt would that mean I'll have twice the range (positive) and it wont overflow?
-- Just tried, unfortunately the Marshal method expects an Int32

Comment: @Marlon - that's my point; it shouldn't because that's the wrong type to represent an HRESULT. You should change it so it is correct.

Comment: sorry for being slow, its late in the day - I can change the interface to return a int32, that's fine. But wouldn't that still overflow as the COM object I'm interacting with is returning something that a int32 can't store.

Comment: The result values of these methods are HRESULTs, which are 32 bit values. They can be stored in a 32 bit integer (int or uint) without any problem.

Comment: just checked the msdn docs and it is indeed returning an int, no idea why it would be returning a value greater than what a int can handle but I guess I'll soon find out if it still isn't working

Comment: The reason would most likely be that you're running on a 64-bit platform, and thus attempting to initialize a 64 bit IntPtr with the 32 bit return value from the P/Invoke method. I'm amazed it actually runs at all to be honest, but the net result will be that the contents of the IntPtr are most likely garbage.